# Set Minimum input value in Ajax/java script

Tags: input, minimum

This code shows error message when there is no value entered. How do i create a coding to have an minimum input of 8 characters?

For Null value:

```
if ($("shipping_tel")) {
            if ($("shipping_tel").value === "") { 
                ErrorMsg += " - Shipping Address: Phone Number\n";
                $("shipping_tel_label").className = 'hilight';
            } else {
                $("shipping_tel_label").className = 'lolight';      
            }
        }
```

For minimum input value:

```
if ($("shipping_tel")) {
            if ($("shipping_tel").value < 8) { 
                ErrorMsg += " - Shipping Address: Phone Number\n";
                $("shipping_tel_label").className = 'hilight';
            } else {
                $("shipping_tel_label").className = 'lolight';      
            }
        }
```

but this does not work. Any idea?

Comment: You are comparing the value with 8 not its length.

Comment: oh..So how can i compare the length? I tried much but didnt work

Comment: Have you tried `$("shipping_tel").value.length < 8` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
str = $("shipping_tel").value;
//This regular expression checks the string.
var patt=/[0-9]{8,}/g;  //atleast 8 nums long.
if(patt.exec(str)!=str){
    ErrorMsg = " - Shipping Address: Phone Number\n";
    $("shipping_tel_label").className = 'hilight';
}else{
    $("shipping_tel_label").className = 'lolight';
}
```

Comment: Hi,so when i insert this, i do not have to have the code which gives the null value error right?

Comment: Nope. This will do that as well.

Comment: Hi, It worked! Just tried!! Thanks for your help! Thanks a million!